# google maps api adding custom icon

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Bit of a strange one - I created a google maps area for a contact page on a site I'm working on. All worked fine voila etc. I went back to change some more stuff on the page today and the icon has completely disappeared. The map still generates and displays fine - only the icon is missing. My img path is still correct and nothing else has changed. I seemed to vaguely remember this happening during original build but it may have fixed itsself. Has anyone else came across similar things?

My JS for the map is here - When I deliberately change to a non existent or non valid var the map wont generate so I;m not entirely certain it is an error with this code.

any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.865151,-2.234739);
        var settings = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
    var companyLogo = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/gmap-icon.png',
    new google.maps.Size(100,50),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(50,50)
);
      var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(51.865151,-2.234739);
      var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: companyPos,
    map: map,
    icon: companyLogo,
    title:"10 Yetis HQ"
});

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation like this , try to  change icon path directly to the physical path

```
Icon: "images/greymarker.png"
```

or else you can even use

```
companyMarker.setIcon("images/bluedot.png");
```

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with browser cache. Clear your cache every time to make a change of you will be seeing a mixed version of changes.

Also, because you are using javascript, most paths are not relative. Try using absolute urls. For example:

```
var companyLogo = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/img/gmap-icon.png', ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you both for the answers :) unfortunately it was something more simple. My JS was executing before my dvi had been rendered in the DOM - I noticed a few errors in the JS console on Chrome and sorted it. thank you both!!